# Is this MLE estimator unbiased?

Tags: expected-value, unbiased-estimator

From 'Modern Mathematical Statistics with Applications' (Devore and Beck) pg 377

> Let $X_1, X_2 \ldots$ be a random sample from the disbribution $f(x,\theta) = \theta x^{\theta-1}$ for $x\in {]0,1[}$ and $\theta >0$.
>
> The MLE is given by $\hat \theta = \dfrac{-n}{\sum_i\ln X_i}$.

It also shows how
$$\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta - \theta) \stackrel{\text{D}}{\rightarrow}N(0,\theta)$$

Using the fact that the MLE is consistent and the CLT.

I wonder if this estimator is also unbiased, I want to show how $E[\hat \theta] = \theta $. Any **ideas** (no full solutions please) on how to (dis)prove this.

Here are some things I've tried:

- Notice how $E[\ln X] = \frac{-1}{\theta}$ or $E[\sum_i \ln X_i]= \dfrac{-n}{\theta}$
- Calculating the expected value seems cumbersome:

$$E\left[\frac{-n}{\sum_i \ln X_i}\right] = \int_0^1\ldots \int_0^1 \frac{-n}{\sum_i \ln x_i} \cdot \theta^n x_1^{\theta-1}x_2^{\theta-1}\ldots x_n^{\theta-1}\operatorname d x_1\ldots \operatorname dx_n$$

#### Edit after the responses from JohnK and Alecos Papadopoulos

- Direct calculation:
  Okay, this is pretty cool. I worked it out and found how $\sum_i -\ln X_i = \sum Y_i \stackrel{\text{d}}{=} \Gamma(n,\theta)$ (through the hints supplied byJohnK), then I immedialty used LOTUS and found $E[\hat \theta] = \dfrac{n}{n-1}\theta > \theta$.
- Jensen's reasoning:
  I guess I should use Jensen's inequality as follows, since $E\left[\sum_i \ln X_i\right] = \dfrac{-n}{\theta}$ and because $\sum_i \ln X_i \in {]-\infty, 0[}$ I should look at the *left* part of the function $g:x\mapsto \dfrac{-n}{x}$ which is stictly convex. Jensen's concludes:
  $$E[g(X)] > g(E[X])$$
  this would imply here:
  $$E[\hat \theta] > \theta$$

Comment: What is wrong with the first remark? - woops, noticed the typo :)

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: Okay, using Jensen's results in $E[\hat \theta] \leqslant \theta$ (since $g: x\mapsto \frac{-n}{x}$ is concave in  $]0,1[$), but this doesn't imply unbiasedness?

Comment: Strict inequality

Comment: Isn't Jensen's inequality always a weak inequality?

Comment: No. The function is strictly concave.

Comment: I couldn't locate a book with that title. Do you mean the book by Devore? If so, please give the correct title. Either way, please also give the author and any other relvant available information (year/edition for example), preferably as a complete reference, so we're not left to guess.

Comment: Since the MLE of a transform is the transform of the MLE, the MLE is almost never unbiased!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sequence of steps that will help:

-Find the distribution of $Y=-\log X$

-Find the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i = - \sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i$

-Lastly, evaluate the expectation of $Z = \frac{1}{\bar{Y}}$. You can do this directly using the distribution of the previous step and [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) or by first finding the distribution of $Z$.

**Hint**: the gamma family is a truly large family of distributions.

Comment: - Since $X = e^{-Y}$ one finds $F_Y(y \theta) = e^{-\theta y}$ or $f_Y(y, \theta) = -\theta e^{-\theta y}$ where $y\in {]0, +\infty[}$, can you expand on the distribution of that sum $\sum_i Y_i$?

Comment: @dietervdf Check your derivation again, that minus sign shouldn't be there. Then for the distribution of the sum, you need to use the additivity property of the gamma family of distributions. If I say more, I will give it away.

Comment: I think I see where you are going, thanks for the hint! Just one thing, why shouldn't the minus be there? My derivation is as follows: $F_X(x,\theta) = x^\theta$ (with $x\in {]0,1[}$, then using the mapping $X = e^{-Y}$ one gets the cdf of $Y$, as $F_Y(y,\theta) = e^{-\theta y}$ which implies $f_Y(y,\theta) = -\theta e^{-\theta y}$

Comment: @dietervdf You you need to take the complement of the CDF as you have a minus there. $\Pr \left( - \log X \leq x \right) = 1-\Pr\left(\log X \leq -x \right)$.

Comment: Okay, the calculations were pretty cool. Thanks! However... I've updated the question, since some conflicting results emerge.

Comment: @dietervdf In what universe is $\frac{n}{n-1} \theta < \theta$?

Comment: Haha, what was I thinking! bummer ;)

Comment: Alternatively, use characteristic functions:
$$\mathbb{E}e^{it(-\log X_1)}=\theta \int_0^1 e^{(\theta - 1 - it) \log x} dx = (1 - it/\theta)^{-1}$$
so
$$\mathbb{E}\exp \left\{-i t \sum \log X_i\right\} = (1-it/\theta)^{-n}.$$